How do we get the Grid item by name programatically in .net maui
In Xamarin I had used
Button button = (Button ) grdOptions.RowDefinitions.Where(c => c.ClassId == "btn" + name).First();
but in .Net maui there is no field for ClassId. Is there any other way I can access the Grid Item?

What is grdOptions? Can you help show the relevant code for it?

Why are you doing this?  Usually accessing the UI this way is a sign you’re doing something wrong
